# PDO prepare error on mixed parameters during insert when there is a mix of ('\','?',':') in strings

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, yii2, sqlsrv

Using Yii2 advanced app with sqlsrv PDO driver v5.9, when inserting multiple strings. There is an error when a string with a trailing slash is put before a string with a question mark if there is also a string with a colon followed by text. In this example, if you put the line with the trailing slash after the line with the question mark it works fine, also if you remove one of either the trailing slash, or question mark, or colon it will work fine as is. I have tried escaping the characters with backslashes and it made no difference.

PDO Errors:

`Caused by: Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An error occurred substituting the named parameters.'`

`Caused by: Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters'`

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (description) VALUES
('test with a trailing slash\'),
('test with a question mark?'),
('test with :colon')";

Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->prepare();
```

**WORKS**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (description) VALUES
('test with a question mark?'),
('test with a trailing slash\'),
('test with :colon')";

Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->prepare();
```

**WORKS**

Removing either of the 3 characters (\, ?, :) works

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (description) VALUES
('test with a question mark'),
('test with a trailing slash\'),
('test with :colon')";

Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->prepare();
```

Comment: Are you trying to use bound parameters?

Comment: PDO accepts `?` as parameter place holders as well as named `:colon` does that answer the question. Because I assume you are only passing one parameter value on the execute :)

Comment: Placeholders (`?` or `:colon`) are stand-alone elements, like `INSERT` OR `test`. If you type a question mark or a colon inside a single-quoted string it isn't a place-holder, it's just regular data.

Comment: Assign the string to a variable and the `bindValue()`.

Comment: I'm not trying to assign any parameters, the strings I have just happen to have those characters in them.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález PDO::prepare appears to be treating the characters in the single quoted string as placeholders.

Comment: Well, it's fair to add that I refer to raw PDO (I've never used Yii). Are you getting an error message complaining about that? All you say in the question is "does not work" :-S

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes, to clarify this is a PDO error, nothing specifically with Yii itself. The actual error is `Caused by: Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An error occurred substituting the named parameters.` and `Caused by: Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters'`

Comment: @Angelo, strange. I receive the similar error with your first statement (`Error executing query. SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An error occurred substituting the named parameters.`) even without using Yii.

Comment: @Zhorov yeah this isn't really related to Yii, its at the PDO level.

Comment: Is it possible that `\ ` character in first string is treated as escape sequence `\'` messing with the rest of strings?

Comment: @MichalHynčica i thought that as well, but just removing the `:` or the `?` and keeping the `\ ` still causes the issue, and as far as i know the prepare statement doesn't escape anything.

Comment: The error complains about mixing named parameter `:colon` and positional parameter `?`. If you remove one of them you are not mixing them anymore even if the strings are messed up. This is just speculation, but maybe PDO is checking the parameters before actually trying to execute SQL and throws that exceptions. When you remove one of `?` or `:` characters the parameter check passes and SQL is executed. The MSSQL doesn't treat `\'` as escape sequence so the strings are actually ok and the query works.

Comment: I haven't worked with SQL Server for a while, but I seem to recall that the SQLSRV extension didn't support one of the two place-holder formats (I don't know if it's still the case). As pointed out, it's possible that the PDO wrapper performs a client-side conversion before submitting the SQL code to the server and the backslash confuses the parser. [Related](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/direct-statement-execution-prepared-statement-execution-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: @MichalHynčica this only occurs during the prepare statement step. I was able to work around it by executing the sql directly. Its looking for parameters to replace because it sees those characters. I assume it must do a check for conflicting parameter types and throw an error if found.

Comment: I have tried your solution but still, it's not working for me can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72976023/6854117)?